# How to search a word in differents subforms

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a form with one subform. The form shows order's info like costumer name, phone number, ease order processing...The subform shows products info, quantities, etc. So I have many forms with their linked subforms.

I would like to create a button to navigate across the subforms to find a particular product.

I have tried a query to make a keyword search like this:

```
SELECT [PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS].PRODUCTO"_
   &FROM [PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS]"_
   &WHERE [PRODUCTOS] LIKE '*"&ME.TXT.KEYWORDS &"*' "_
   &ORDER BY [PRODUCTOS PEDIDOS]. PRODUCTO "
```

But it isn't what I need because it brings me a table with the records that contains the product's name. Instead, I just need to go to the registers in different subforms from different orders forms that include the product's name, like default search button, but searching across all the subforms.

Thanks

EDIT: I explained wrong I have just one form and one subform, I supose the subform is filtered by linked field PEDIDO. So when I tried to find some records, I can only search in the linked records but not in others. I tried a recordset clone, (thanks for your suggestion, Doug), but I get the same. I tried this code:

```
Private Sub Comando881_Click()
       Dim strCriterio As String
       Dim rstPRODUCTOS_PEDIDOS As DAO.Recordset


       strCriterio = "producto = '" & Me.txtkey & "'"

       Set rstPRODUCTOS_PEDIDOS = Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.Form.RecordsetClone


       rstPRODUCTOS_PEDIDOS.FindFirst strCriterio

        If rstPRODUCTOS_PEDIDOS.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "No hay registros"
    Else

    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.Form.Bookmark = rstPRODUCTOS_PEDIDOS.Bookmark
    End If

   End Sub
```

Comment: Well it seems as if your subforms already have that information - cant you just query based off of that? Or make a recordset clone? Or Dlookup the query the subform is based one with your criteria?

Comment: Hi, Doug, thanks for your answer, I tried recordset clone, but I couldn't get what I need. I edited my original post with the used code.